# Automate the creation of database/user/password into K8 for Bitnami helm chart postgresql

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, bitnami, helm

I'm deploying the https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql into k8s and wondering how can I automate the following

- creation of a database
- create a role with password as owner of the database above

I've seen the `extraDeploy` https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/postgresql/values.yaml#L43
parameter but this seems like will create a k8s specific resource (not touching pg).

The only idea I have leveraging the `extraDeploy` is to create a job which deploys a custom pod that will connect to pg and create the db, role and password ...

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here, you can use an initial script to create the database and all the things you need with `initdbScripts`:
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/931b597c43f6cd37919569acda4432a9bdd59a71/bitnami/postgresql/values.yaml#L298-L307

You can check the "[Initialize a fresh instance](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql#initialize-a-fresh-instance)" part of the README.md for more information.

Comment: Thanks - I'm using the initdbScripts with a custom sql script.

Comment: initdbScripts is a nice solution. Only addition is that I needed to escape the "." in the filename/dictionary key, e.g. `01_init\.sql:`

Comment: More details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499984/postgresql-in-helm-initdbscripts-parameter

Comment: @lbone hey, ConfigMaps have a limit of 1MB . is there a way to deploy a new db from the .sql backup of another one?